# Error while editing Jasny boootstrap - Getting "Ruh roh ! Could not parse less files?" error message

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I am trying to customize Jasny boostrap navmenu with custom colors of Yeti Bootswatch theme
at

All I've changed is(See attached image):

```
@navmenu-inverse-color: #fff;
@navmenu-inverse-bg: @brand-primary;
@navmenu-inverse-border: darken(@navbar-inverse-bg, 10%);
```

I am getting an error saying that it cannot compile the less file.

What error I am making?

Please help

[image: Error Image here]

**EDIT:**

I followed @seven-phases-max's advice and did the changes. Now It shows another error?
See the attached image.

[image]

Comment: Basically this means (the error is at the second line of the alert) that there no such variable as `@brand-primary` defined in the JBS files...
If I understand it correctly the only variables you can use within these fields *are* actually listed at this page, no more than that (and if you need something more -> download and edit those files manually, incl. importing variables from wherever).

Comment: see the edit in my question..

Comment: In other words if you need to include Yeti variables there - you nee to import Yeti `variables.less` into the JBS less sources. And it's impossible cannot do this with this customer page.

Comment: I read this on SO. But I am new to this and tried doing this and failed badly.

Comment: What do you mean by importing? Copying and pasting? If yes, what needs to be copied and pasted?

Comment: Answering your new image: the same error once more: there's **no**  `@navbar-inverse-bg` variable in JBS (there's only `@navmenu-inverse-bg`).

Comment: >What do you mean by importing? - By importing I mean you have to download JBS and Yeti Less sources and manually add `@import "path-to-yeti-source/variables.less";` statement at the end of the master JBS file. And then compile all this to CSS. See Less ["Import" documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature). Without such statement you **can't** use Yeti variables in the JSB sources. You definitely need to read/watch some tutorials on using Less and Less-based frameworks.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Yup that's the correct answer. Can you use the answer field below, for future reference? Thanks!

Comment: @Arnold I'm not sure I know how to present all that info in a clear straight-forward way. So please feel free to answer yourself.